# how to resize image in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I capture an image using the photo or camera task and I want to resize the image to say example 480x240 from the captured size of around  2592x1944. 
how do I do this ? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the JPEG stream you get from the Completed event to the [PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708027%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) method. The second and the third parameters define the size. You will get a WriteableBitmap that can be manipulated further and saved back to the MediaLibrary. See [this blog post](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2010/07/photos-photos-photos-how-to-save-load.html) for some example.

Comment: thanks for the response.  after decodeJpeg if I want to convert the resulting WriteableBitmap to BitmapImage. What is the best way to do it ? or is there way to directly resize bitmapimage ?